# underscore some method giving unexpected result

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

I am trying to replace the following bit of code with a call to  `_.some` in the underscore library

```
var anyInTopRow = false;

            for (var g = 0; g < this.grid[1].length; g++ ) {
                if (this.grid[1][g] != undefined) {
                    anyInTopRow = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
```

underscore's some/any method:

```
var anyInTopRow = _.some(this.grid[1], function(x) {x != undefined;});
```

but they return different results with the same data

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not returning anything. Try

```
var anyInTopRow = _.some(this.grid[1], function(x) {return x != undefined;});
```

Comment: `jshint` or equivalent would alert you to this sort of problem: `my_script.js: line 1, col 22, Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.`.